# how to pass two array variable in one another array variable for searching in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have two array and i am inserting this two array another one array for displaying data on tableview cell but how to fetch name from first array and report from second array

for eg:
i am doing this

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]      initWithObjects:self.ListOfname,self.ListOfpeople,nil];


    [self.list addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
```

In myArray i am passing two array first listofname and second listofpeople  here i getting 
proper but how to display two diffrent array value from one array variable on tableview cell

And my self.ListOfname array variable value is coming from this class Namecontrooler.m
And my self.ListOfpeople array variable value coming from this class Peoplecontroller.m

so my question is how to retrive this class value and print on tableview cell by one array
i am doing this on cell for row at indexpath this is right for display value

```
Namecontrooler*Name=(Namecontrooler*)[self.list  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Peoplecontroller*people=(Peoplecontroller*)[self.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

here i not getting how to display both class value in on tableview cell please help me here how to do this

Comment: What are the types for `Namecontrooler` and `Peoplecontroller`? Also why are you adding this to an array?

Comment: i don't understand you question.

Comment: parth bhatt in namecontroler i have name variable and peopelcontroler i have people name so i want this two variable print from one array so pleae tell me how to do

Answer (score 2):

I think your self.list contains only two objects 1>ListOfName 2>ListOfPeople .So  before accessing object at index of indexPath.row,First take out which object u want out of two and then with reference to indexPath.row take out object at particular object.

Comment: I mean  NSArray* names=[self.list objectAtIndex:0];
      NSArray* people=[self.list objectAtIndex:1];
     Namecontrooler*Name= [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     Peoplecontroller*people= [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     Hope it helps